# Trouble relating second object for dynamically added records From Controller Extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic, extension

I'm editing this, as I just realized that the two objects are being saved, but they are not being related.  These two objects are related via lookup.  I'm relatively new to coding, and haven't been able to identify my error.  Below is my VF Page and the Controller.  This has been built off a reference from this blog: https://prats23.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/salesforce-dynamically-addingdeleting-rows-in-visualforce/

VF Page

```
 <apex:page standardController="Loan_Memo__c" extensions="fieldDynamicExtension">
    <apex:form>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Field Exam" id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Loan_Memo__c.Loan__c }" />
                <apex:inputField value="{! Loan_Memo__c.Relationship__c }" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>




            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!keep}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}" />
            <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable title="Field Exam" var="fe" value="{!examList}">

                    <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
                        <apex:outputText value="{0}" style="text-align:center;">
                            <apex:param value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Field Examiner Recommendation:">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!fe.Field_Examiner_Recommendation__c}" style="width:500px" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Relationship Manager Response:">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!fe.Relationship_Manager_Response__c}" style="width:700px" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pb">
                            <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}" />
                        </apex:commandButton>
                        <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Recommendation" reRender="pb" />
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extension Class:

```
public class fieldDynamicExtension {

    public Loan_Memo__c myMemo       {get;set;}
    public FieldExam__c myExam    {get;set;}
    public List<FieldExam__c> addexamList {get;set;}
    public List<FieldExam__c> delexamList {get;set;}
    public List<FieldExam__c> examList    {get;set;}
    public Integer totalCount             {get;set;}
    public Integer rowIndex               {get;set;}
    public List<FieldExam__c> delExam {get; set;} 
    public fieldDynamicExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
    {
        myMemo  = (Loan_Memo__c)sc.getRecord();
        myExam= new FieldExam__c();

        examList = [Select id, Field_Examiner_Recommendation__c, Relationship_Manager_Response__c from FieldExam__c where LoanMemo__c =: myMemo.Id];
        totalCount = examList.size();

        delexamList  = new List<FieldExam__c>();
        delExam = new List<FieldExam__c>();
    }

    public void addRow(){
        addexamList = new List<FieldExam__c>();
        examList.add(new FieldExam__c(LoanMemo__c = myMemo.Id));
    }

    public ApexPages.PageReference keep(){
        insert examList;
        delete delexamList;
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(myMemo)).Save();   
    }      
    public void deleteRow(){
        rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
        System.debug('row to be deleted ' + rowIndex );
        System.debug('row item to be deleted '+examList[rowIndex]);
        myExam = examList.remove(rowIndex);
        delexamList.add(myExam);
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for any assistance.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, can you please [edit] your post to include it? If you do so, you can use the `>` character before error messages to make them easier to find.

Comment: I am not getting an error, but the records are not saved.

Comment: Do you have problem with examList ?

Comment: yes, how do I assign the related object field id to this list?

Comment: I highly recommend you to read [VisualForce in practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf),
it will help you to understand binding etc. In your page too many mistakes

Comment: Thanks, any specific pointers to this particular issue?

Comment: you probably missing id in addrow: try examList.add(new FieldExam__c(LoanMemo__c = myMemo.id));

Comment: I tried adding that, but it is still not relating the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through possible scenarios:

- Insert single record and save - ok
- remove single record and save - ok
- click save with existing record - nok

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

You inserting existing record, change insert to upsert:

```
upsert examList;
```

- add single record (no save) and remove it - nok

You attempting to delete record with not specified id

> Missing id at index: 0

Insert to delexamList only if Id exist:

```
if (!string.isblank(myExam.id))
    delexamList.add(myExam);
```

New records are assigned to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that this could be solved with a for loop in the keep section of the controller.  This would probably of been obvious to those with experience.  Thanks to everyone who posted to help me out.

```
public ApexPages.PageReference keep(){
    upsert mymemo;
    for (FieldExam__c Exams : examList){
        Exams.LoanMemo__c = myMemo.Id;}
    upsert examList;
    return (new ApexPages.StandardController(myMemo)).Save();
```